# Live OCR Flutter

Tags: flutter, ocr, firebase-mlkit, google-mlkit, east-text-detector

I'm creating flutter app like google lens where I want to select specific word from image by touching on that word like google lens text recognization. How I can I achieve this. It will be good if it can be done with google or firebase ml kit.

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do is to run ML Kit OCR on the image, and keep the detected words from the image. When you click on the screen, you could compare the touch point with the OCR detection results. If the touch point within one result, you know the detected word is selected.

Because ML Kit OCR detection results could be a character, a word or a sentence. It is your decision what should be selected.